# Где поставить запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

**"В настоящее время, вышеуказанный гараж, находится на праве оперативного управления за государственным учреждением..."**

Answer (score 2):

**Здесь нет запятых.**

Необособленное обстоятельство (детерминант) в начале предложения относится ко всему предложению.  Такие обстоятельства обособляются только при значительной распространенности (обычно оборот в этом случае содержит производный предлог).

Вышеуказанный гараж  ― это группа подлежащего, обособляться не может.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу понять, как связаны слова в этом отрывке. Некорректно как "находится на праве" , так и "находится за учреждением". Но если рассмотреть укороченый отрывок **"В настоящее время вышеуказанный гараж находится..."**, то можно утверждать, что запятые в нем не нужны.